# How to install python tkinter on yocto image

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, yocto, xilinx

I am trying to install a python package called tkinter onto my xilinx kria board which is running on pentalinux.

Have tried several methods such as:
pip3 install tkinter
pip3 install pytk
pip3 install tk

However as pentalinux does not have apt-get I am unable to utlize this command to install tkinter.

Does anyone has any solutions to this? Thank you.

Comment: apt is Debian + Debian clones only. The other 600 "Linux OS" have a variety of other install tools / commands for package install.  PetaLinux hint https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/73296.html .... I.e. please use Google to search for ' petalinux install packages ' .